# wp_insert_post action causes 503 service unavailable

Tags: wordpress

For a custom post type in WordPress, I want to automatically use the post ID as a slug for the post. For this, I use the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'change_slug', 10, 3 );
function change_slug( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'custom_post_type' ) {
        return;
    }
    
    wp_update_post(
        array(
            'ID'        => $post_id,
            'post_name' => $post_id, // slug
        )
    );
}
```

This code is based on a previous answer on so: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160483/181877

However, using this code I cannot even open the new post page for this CPT in WordPress. instead, I get a 503 Service unavailable message, which I believe is caused by a timeout.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Any pointers?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check whether this results in an infinite loop?

Comment: Hi Nico, it seemed like it indeed went into an infinite loop. I have just tried checking the $update variable to only have the code run on a new post and not during an update, and now it seems to work. Will answer my own question below :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

It seems like it resulted in an infinite loop, not sure why. But I included an extra if statement to check for the `$update` variable, making sure the code is not run during the update of a post and only when a new one is published. This seemed to have resolved it.

Below is my final code:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'change_slug', 10, 3 );
function change_slug( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'custom_post_type' ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $update ) { // added this
        return;
    }

    wp_update_post(
        array(
            'ID'        => $post_id,
            'post_name' => $post_id,
        )
    );
}
```